# Double for loop in MATLAB, storing the information

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have two for loops in MATLAB.

One of the for loops leads to different variables being inserted into the model, which are 43 and then I have 5 horizons.

So I estimate the model 215 times.

My problem is I want to store this in 215x5 matrix, the reason I have x5 is that I am estimating 5 variables, 4 are fixed and the other one comes from the for loop.

I have tried to do this in two ways,

Firstly, I create a variable called out,

```
out=zeros(215,5);
```

The first for loop is,

```
for i=[1,2,3,4,5];
```

The second for loop is,

```
for  ii=18:60;
```

The 18:60 is how I define my variables using XLS read, e.g. they are inserted into the model as (data:,ii).

I have tried to store the data in two ways, I want to store OLS which contains the five estimates

First,

```
out(i,:)=OLS;
```

This method creates a 5 x 5 matrix, with the estimates for one of the (18:60), at each of the horizons.

Second,

```
out(ii,:)=OLS;
```

This stores the variables for each of the variables (18:60), at just one horizon.

I want to have a matrix which stores all of the estimates OLS, at each of the horizons, for each of my (18:60).

Minimal example

```
clear;

for i=[1,2,3,4,5];
    K=i; 
    for  ii=18:60
        x=[1,2,3,i,ii];
        out(i,:)=x;       
    end
end
```

So the variable out will store `1 2 3 5 60`

I want the variable out to store all of the combinations

i.e.

```
1 2 3 1 1
1 2 3 1 2
  ...
1 2 3 5 60
```

Thanks

Comment: please, show a [mcve]. Replace `OLS` by  `rand(5,5)`. Text description of code is hard to understand, specially when you can show code! However, the way it looks now you have 2 loops, of size 45*5=215 and in each you call OLS, of size 25. So you need out to be 215x25, no?

Comment: I'll work on this, Thanks.

Comment: I have added an example that I think is ok! Let me know

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with 5x5 matrix in the text? `x` there is 1x5, not 5x5

Comment: Please, don't use `i` and `ii`. That is just asking for confusion. Why not `ii` and `jj`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've discovered, using just one of your loop variables to index the output results in most of the results being overwritten, leaving only the results from the final iteration of the relevant loop.

There are 2 ways to create an indexing variable.

**1-** You can use an independent variable, initialised before the loops and incremented at the end of the internal loop.

```
kk=1; 
for i=1:5
    for ii=18:60
        %calculate OLC
        out(kk,:)=OLC;
        kk = kk+1;
    end 
end
```

**2-** Use a calculation of `i` and `ii`

```
kk = i + 5*(ii-18)
```

(Use in loop as before, without increment)

Comment: Thanks @AnderBiguri the first options appears to be fine in my minimal example.

Comment: @AnderBiguri thanks, I'd swapped which way around I put `i` and `ii` in the calculation and forgot to include the higher starting value

Comment: Try not to use `i` as the loop index as it overwrites the MATLABs imaginary unit and can lead to tricky to find bugs.

Comment: Also you can calculate `kk` from `i` and `ii` with  MATLABs builtin function `sub2ind`.

Comment: Note that the first block and the second one yield a different output order, as MATLAB stores data column-wise.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use a 3D matrix:

```
for jj=[1,2,3,4,5];
    K=jj;
    for ii=18:60
        x=[1,2,3,jj,ii];
        out(ii-17,jj,:)=x;       
    end
end
```

If you now reshape the `out` matrix you get the same result as the first block in etmuse's answer:

```
out = reshape(out,[],size(out,3));
```

(Note I replaced `i` by `jj`. `i` and `ii` are too similar to use both, it leads to confusion. It is better to use different letters for loop indices. Also, `i` is OK to use, but it also is the built-in imaginary number sqrt(-1). So I prefer to use `ii` over `i`.)