# For loop storing values in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

I have asked a similar question before, see,

[Double for loop in MATLAB, storing the information](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51967345/5211833)

I am storing the results from a for loop but this time my for loop numbers do not increase by one each time.

```
%% 
for q = [25,50,100,250,500,5000]

ActualTable(:,q)=ActualValues;
end
```

As you will see this code runs but it has large portions of rows in the matrix `ActualTable` which only contain `0`'s I would just like the rows that contain non-zero. So it is saving every single row from 25 to 5000 and only inserting my values in the `25, 50, 100` etc rows with all other rows containing a zero.

Comment: Ok so if q was 1:10 this would work fine! Storing the values in a matrix! But now, it create a very big matrix and only stores information on the 25, 50, 100, 250, 500 and 5000 rows, I just was a matrix with 6 rows not 5000

Answer (score 4):

```
for q = [25,50,100,250,500,5000]
    ActualTable(:,q)=ActualValues;
end
```

This says that MATLAB should loop over `q`, where `q` has six possible values. If `q=25`, the inner call will store `ActualValues` in column `q`, which is, as just said, 25. So of course using this `q` array you get a `N`*-by-*`5000` matrix, since the last column you attempt to store something in is 5000, and MATLAB does not do Swiss cheese in matrices.

Instead, loop over a monotonically increasing index:

```
for ii = 1:numel(q)
    ActualTable(ii,:) = ActualValues(q(ii),:); % You said rows, let's use rows then
end
```

This way you have just 6 rows, since `numel(q)=6`, and get the data based on the `ii`th value of `q` out of `ActualValues`.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming with the way that you have displaye it that ActualValues is just 1 value each time.  The problem with your code is that q has increments other than 1. The solution is to append the value at the end each time or to use a counter.

Append:

```
ActualTable = [];
for q = [25,50,100,250,500,5000]
ActualTable(end+1)=ActualValues;
end
```

Count:

```
ActualTable = [];
c = 1;
for q = [25,50,100,250,500,5000]
ActualTable(c)=ActualValues;
c = c+1;
end
```

Note that changing the length of the array each time is not good coding practice.  If you know how many final values there are going to be, you should instantiate ActualTable with that length.

Comment: *If you know how many final values there are going to be*, well yeah, I assume he does, as he has already put them there, in `q`.